# Add the ability for a button to change one field in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a fetched all the data from the MySQL database and put it in an array. After displaying the data, I need to add a button that will be displayed after each order, and that when click will update the 'status' field of that orders from 'incomplete' to 'complete'. Below is the code so far.

```
    <?php 
 // Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
 mysql_select_db("orders_db") or die(mysql_error()) ; 

 //Retrieves data from MySQL 
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orders") or die(mysql_error());  //Puts it into an array 
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 

 //Outputs the data

 Echo "<h2> Order For: ".$info['name'] . "</h2> "; 

  if ($info['year']=="Staff member") {
     Echo "".$info['year'] . " <br>"; 
     } else {
      Echo "Year: ".$info['year'] . " <br>"; 
      }

 if ($info['id']=="Cash/Eftpos") {
     Echo "Payment via: ".$info['id'] . " <br>"; 
     } else {
      Echo "Payment charged to Student account: ".$info['id'] . " <br>"; 
      }

 Echo "Collection Time: ".$info['time'] . " <br>"; 
 Echo "Beverage Type: ".$info['beverage'] . " <br>"; 
 Echo "status: ".$info['status'] . " <hr>";

 }

?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll likely want to make the button a submit button in a form with a hidden field containing the ID of that order - or whatever the primary key for that table is. Then in the file that the form submits to, you'll want to take in the ID of that form, like so (assuming you're POSTing your data):

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
```

And then use MySQL's UPDATE to update that row, like so:

```
$sql = "UPDATE orders SET status = 'complete' WHERE id = {$id}";
mysql_query($sql);
```

You'll want this file to either output some success message or redirect you back to your order list page. Whatever makes sense in your flow.

ALSO:

There are a number of issues with your code and architecture. I would suggest moving your DB connect logic into a separate file that you can load up whenever you connect to your DB. That way your database credentials are in one place and if they change you only need to change them there. There's a little bit of a learning curve, but I'd also look into an MVC architecture, maybe using a framework like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) or [Code Igniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter). This will really help your work flow in the long run and make creating web apps a lot cleaner and easier to maintain.

Also, `echo` is usually not capitalized. I'd read up on [Zend's Coding conventions](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html). Zend is a big contributor to the PHP engine and they create [the most used PHP framework](http://framework.zend.com/).

Finally, look into the [PHP mysqli extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), it's a  more modern implementation of PHP's mysql connection logic and depending on what version you're running the straight mysql extension might even be deprecated. The basic stuff is pretty much one to one conversion so there shouldn't be anything new to learn.